# Find the time for more than K customers present in the hotel

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, genetic-algorithm

if there are more than K customers present in the hotel at any given moment ,then period of time is called P period.

**Task is to determine the P period**

Input format
first line contains n and k and next n lines contain check-in and check-out time of the ith customer
Test Case:

```
3 2
5 8
2 4
3 9
```

Output:4

If I am not wrong we have to find the time at which more than K customers present at the moment.
my code

```
def hotel(n,k,A):
    count=0
    dp=[1]*n
    for i in range(n):
        I1=A[i][0]
        o1=A[i][1]
        time=[]
        for j in range(i+1,n):
            I2=A[j][0]
            o2=A[j][1]
            if I1>=I2 and I1<o2:
                dp[i]=dp[i]+1
                if o1<=o2:
                    time.append(o1-I1)
                else:
                    time.append(o2-I1)
            elif I1<I2 and o1>I2:
                dp[i]=dp[i]+1
                if o1>o2:
                    time.append(o2-I2)
                else:
                    time.append(o1-I2)
        if dp[i]>=k:
            count+=sum(time)
    return count
```

Problem it showing wrong answer with code
can anyone help.

Comment: Could you give an example of your code giving the wrong answer? Please be more specific.

Comment: I do not have more test case.

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
Your posted code defines a function and quits without executing.  You haven't shown any work to trace the problem yourself.

Comment: Actually Question is  from hackerearth's contest  which I submitted .I just wanna know where i go wrong in this problem

Comment: Could you explain why you get `4` with your test case?  Or mayby a P period corresponds to a number of customers *equal or* higher than K.

Comment: this is the exact test case in the question.I also consider K equal .

Comment: You are looking for the longest subsets of time periods that are present in at least k sets. In the example the longest subset is `[5,6,7,8]` which is included in customer 1 and 3. The length of this subset is 4, leading to the answer `P=4`.

Comment: I don't think  so we are looking for longest subset of time periods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sample result (4) suggests that we are looking for the total number of days where at least K (not more than) customers are present.  The problem statement also doesn't specify if the check out day is included or excluded from the periods (which gives the same answer for this data but may differ on other samples).

In any case, you can compute these values using list comprehensions and sums:

```
n = 3
K = 2
A = [(5,8),(2,4),(3,9)]

checkIns,checkOuts = zip(*A)
firstDay  = min(checkIns)
lastDay   = max(checkOuts)
counts    = [ sum(day in range(inTime,outTime) for inTime,outTime in A)
              for day in range(firstDay,lastDay+1) ]
P         = sum(count >= K for count in counts)
print(P) # 4
```

The `counts` list is built by going through every possible day and counting, for each day, how many customers were present.  Counting customers for a given day goes through the check-in/check-out times (in `A`) to check if that day is within the customer's presence period.

*note: `range(inTime,outTime)` above assumes that check-out days are excluded. Change it to `range(inTime,outTime+1)` if they are to be included*

Comment: @Damien, You are right of course, I didn't thing that through.  I changed the variable names to days instead of hours to avoid future confusion.

Comment: I also did same thing in my code